# solving quadratic and linear congruences with different modulus

Tags: core-language, number-theory

We are able to solve the quadratic congruences

$C^2 + Q^4 - 2\equiv mod 3072$ 
and
$C - Q^2 - 2046\equiv mod 3072$

by entering

```
Reduce[{C^2 + Q^4 - 2 == 0, C - Q^2 - 2046== 0}, Q, Modulus -> 3072]
```

However we want to further filter the results by defining $Q \equiv 1 mod 768$ and $C\equiv 511 mod 1536 $.
Which command should we enter?
Thank you...

Comment: Let me define the new variables `Q1` and `C1`. Now, you can consider `Q` and `C` just as `1 + 768 * Q1` and `511 + 1536 * C1` correspondingly. So your code is `Reduce[{(511 + 1536 * C1)^2 + (1 + 768 * Q1)^4 - 2 ==0, (511 + 1536 * C1) - (1 + 768 * Q1)^2 - 2046 == 0}, Q1, Modulus -> 3072].

Comment: To broaden the question, if we have to add different conditions for different modulus, what should we do?

Comment: Do you want the main congruences getting fixed while you can add the extra restrictions to their variables?

Comment: Let's say we want to set an extra restiction modulus 7,11.. etc...

Comment: Maybe `sol = Solve[{c^2 + q^4 - 2 == 0, c - q^2 - 2046 == 0, q == k*768 + 1},
    q, Modulus -> 3072, MaxExtraConditions -> 2];`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the function `Solve` and `Select` will help.

```
set = (Solve[c^2 + Q^4 - 2 == 0 && c - Q^2 - 2046 == 0, {c, Q}, 
Modulus -> 3072]);
Select[set, 
Mod[(#)[[1, 2]], 1536] == 511 && Mod[(#)[[2, 2]], 768] == 1 &]
```

The result is

> {{c->511,Q->769},{c->511,Q->2305},{c->2047,Q->1},{c->2047,Q->1537}}

We'd better to use `c` than `C` since the later one has its own meaning in Mathematica.

Comment: Using Reduce[{C^2 + Q^4 - 2 == 0, C - Q^2 - 2046 == 0}, C, Modulus -> 3072] we get a solution like: Q == 1 && C == 2047, So your  Solve, Select combination needs revision.

Comment: @Kurtul Thanks! I update the answer.